# Is there a way to prevent a non-terminal-attached process from executing 'who' inside my .envfile?

Tags: ksh, aix, who

I made some modifications to the `/home/user/.envfile` so the `PS1` prompt would show date/time as well as the `pwd` etc.

The modification is:

```
# `who am i` is used to obtain the name of the original user
case `who am i | awk '{print $1}'` in
    'someuser')
        #set the prompt to include the date and time
        set -o allexport
        unset _Y _M _D _h _m _s
        eval $(date "+_Y=%Y;_M=%m;_D=%d;_h=%H;_m=%M;_s=%S")
        ((SECONDS = 3600*${_h#0}+60*${_m#0}+${_s#0}))
        typeset -Z2 _h _m _s
        _tsub="(_m=(SECONDS/60%60)) == (_h=(SECONDS/3600%24)) + (_s=(SECONDS%60))"
        _timehm='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:${_m}'
        _timehms='${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
        _timedhms=$_Y'/'$_M'/'$_D" "'${_x[_tsub]}$_h:$_m:${_s}'
        _hn=`hostname`
        typeset -u _hn
        # `whoami` is used here to display the name of the 'su' user
        _un=`whoami | awk '{print $1}'`
        typeset -u _un
        export PS1="$_timedhms
"'['$_un']'$_hn':${PWD#$HOME/} $ '
        set +o allexport
    ;;
    *)
    ;;
esac
```

The prompt should look like:

```
2014/08/07 11:08:24
[su'd username]hostname:/home/username $
```

As you can see, this makes use of `whoami` to display the name of the current user in the prompt.

Certain processes we run through this account are complaining:

```
who: 0551-012 The process is not attached to a terminal.
        Do not run who am i as a background process.
Usage: who [-AabdHilmpqrsTtuwX?] [am {i,I}] [utmp_like_file]
```

Is there any way to prevent that modification from affecting this other process?  Possibly by detecting when the process is not attached to a terminal?

Comment: The usual workaround to avoid complaints from `who am i` and `stty` is to surround then in an `if [ -t 0 ]; then ... ; fi` statement. In this case, you can surround the entire logic that sets up the PS1 variable in that `if`, since PS1 only makes sense when you're working on a tty.

Comment: Your question doesn't explain why you need `who am i` rather than `id -un` or something simpler.

Comment: I used `who am i` since that is the command I am familiar with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[stty](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/stty.html) and older versions of [who am i](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/who.html) will issue error messages when they're not connected to a tty device. `stty` checks stdin (fd 0); I don't know what file descriptor `who` checks. To avoid getting those error messages, the usual workaround has been to use the `-t` option of [test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/test.html) (more commonly known as `[`) to check if the shell is connected to a tty.

```
if [ -t 0 ]
then
    ID=`who am i | awk '{print $1}'`
else
    ID="unknown"
fi
```

In your case, you can surround the entire logic that sets up the PS1 variable in that `if` statement, since PS1 only makes sense when one is working on a tty.

The following is the relevant section from the explanation of `test` in the link above.

> -t  file_descriptor
>
> True if file descriptor number file_descriptor is open and is associated with a terminal. False if file_descriptor is not a valid file descriptor number, or if file descriptor number file_descriptor is not open, or if it is open but is not associated with a terminal.

Comment: I was wondering what `[ -t 0 ]` did.  Thanks for the explanation and the link to `test`!

Answer (score 3):

Your script, at the first time is using `who` not `whoami`. Change it and you should get the result you expect.

Comment: The first case statement returns the actual user logged in, the `whoami` is used to show who you've `su'd` to, so I cannot make the change you suggested.

Comment: @Max Please update the question to mention this.

Comment: I've added some comments to the code sample, and added the desired prompt.

Comment: Have a +1 for pointing out that `whoami` does not exhibit the same behavior as `who am i`